# VB.NET WPF Style Changes on Flow Document Combo Boxes Generate Exceptions That Trigger Successful Operation?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox, code-behind, flowdocument

The following code formats the ComboBox background color in a WPF Flow Document.

```
Try

    objHold = New Object

    objHold = objCombo.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", objCombo)

    tbTemp = New TextBox

    tbTemp = objHold

    objCheck = New Object

    objCheck = tbTemp.Template.FindName("PART_ContentHost", tbTemp)

    If objCheck.GetType = GetType(ScrollViewer) Then

       svTemp = New ScrollViewer

       svTemp = objCheck

       With svTemp

      .Background = New SolidColorBrush(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(strTheme(11)))

       End With

    End If

Catch ex As Exception

    MsgBox(ex.Message & " " & ex.StackTrace, vbExclamation, "Operation Failed!")

End Try
```

It doesn't do this alone, but it's part of a loop that functions properly EXCEPT for this part:

1. When the system first attempts to format a combo box, it traverses the template in an attempt to locate where to format the background color.
2. The first element it reaches is the `"PART_EditableTextBox"` which almost invariably goes off without a hitch.
3. When the system attempts to get the `"PART_ContentHost"` it crashes, displaying "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object," and the affected line of code.
4. After the first failure on any combo box in the loop, ***the procedure SUCCEEDS***.
5. The procedure will successfully locate the `"PART_ContentHost"` and transfer it to the `ScrollViewer` object.
6. Once the `ScrollViewer` is working, the rest of the program mysteriously becomes able to set the background of the combo box.
7. This is, of course, only able to happen *after* announcing that it failed.

To the best of my knowledge, it literally HAS to announce its failure in order to succeed.  Attempting to eliminate `Try`, `Catch ex As Exception`, and `End Try` doesn't work.  Once `Try..Catch..End Try` is gone, the program will execute without formatting any combo boxes.

Commenting out the message box is also not the answer.  It just causes the program to skip formatting any combo boxes.

I'm not finding any way to test for a null reference without *crashing*.  When I attempt to test for an error condition before there's an actual error, it either triggers a message box on that line, or the whole program just skips the part about formatting combo boxes at all.

Remember, with everything in place as-is, the program does run, and does successfully update the background color of any combo box it finds in the loop.  It just doesn't do it without throwing a temper tantrum.  When I launch testing in Visual Studio, sometimes the message box will appear as few as once per Flow Document, but when I run the .exe file from the folder, it will display a message box for each combo box it finds, but sometimes more.

It's the flurry of message boxes I want to avoid, not the entire functionality of the program.  Is there a way to solve this without giving up the entire functionality of the program?

Comment: The message boxes are happening because your code is throwing exceptions.  Fix the problems that are causing the exceptions, and you won't see the message boxes.

Comment: `When I attempt to test for an error condition before there's an actual error` -- The error condition that you should be checking *first* is whether the object is null.

Comment: Testing for null.  How?  Each time I've tried testing for null, I got "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  In other words, testing for null produces a null that crashes the program at a different line, instead of the original.  How do I avoid that?

Comment: Then you're doing your null check wrong.  `if(object == null) { // handle error }`

Comment: `Attempting to eliminate Try, Catch ex As Exception, and End Try doesn't work.` -- That's because you're *guessing.*  Guessing won't work; you have to carefully work through the logic, identify the errors and repair them.  Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It currently crashes at `objCheck = tbTemp.Template.FindName("PART_ContentHost", tbTemp)`, but I don't see an obvious way to check this.  I don't know how to handle the specific error, and now I'm getting "Object reference..." AND a new error "Operator '<>' is not defined for type 'ScrollViewer' and 'Nothing'."  It's no longer formatting the combo boxes either.

Comment: .ApplyTemplate() answers this question, but it's not marked as an answer in stack overflow, because it's in a comment.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450816/how-to-get-at-the-wpf-combobox-part-editabletextbox-because-combobox-not-getti

Comment: `objCheck = tbTemp.Template.FindName("PART_ContentHost", tbTemp)` can be checked for nulls like this: `if (tbTemp == null || tbTemp.Template == null) { // handle error }`

Comment: Or: `if (tbTemp != null && tbTemp.Template != null) { // call FindName() }`

Comment: But ultimately you probably ought to try and avoid null references in the first place.

Comment: To @RobertHarvey 's comments on null checks, in VB you should be checking for e.g.  `tbTemp Is Nothing` or `tbTemp IsNot Nothing`.

Comment: @Craig, the biggest problem was that testing certain things for `IsNot Nothing` was triggering the exact same "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.."  If the thing you're trying to test for triggers the thing you're trying to avoid, you can't avoid it.  This looks more like a glitch to me, because if you invoke `objTest.ApplyTemplate()` before searching the template, you'll get results without error messages, by avoiding `Nothing`.  If you don't invoke it, somehow you still get results, because **the error doesn't stop** the program from running.

Comment: If you're getting a nullrefexception on a check against `Nothing`, you're missing something.  It might be a case where you should be using a null conditional operator `?.` (then you can effectively check for nulls at every level of a chain), or it might be that you're using `And` instead of `AndAlso` or omitting a check on a higher-level component.  In either case, you should make sure you have the debugger set to break on thrown nullrefexceptions (by default it only breaks when uncaught) and inspect the variables when it breaks to see which one is null.